# Copy file using relative path

Tags: c#, copy, relative-path

```
File.Copy(@"my program\\subfolder\\what i want to copy.txt", "C:\\Targetlocation");
```

How can i copy a text file from one folder to another using relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute the `File.Copy` the source and destination will be a valid file path. in your case the destination is a folder not File. in this case you may get some exception like

> *Could not find a part of the path 'F:\New folder'*

While executing the application, the current directory will be the `bin` folder. you need to specify the relative path from there. Let `my program/subfolder` be the folders in your solution, so the code for this will be like this:

```
string sourcePath = "../../my program/subfolder/what i want to copy.txt";
string destinationPath = @"C:\Targetlocation\copyFile.txt"
File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath );
```

Where `../` will help you to move one step back from the current directory. One more thing you have to care is the third optional parameter in the `File.Copy` method. By passing `true` for this parameter will help you to overwrite the contents of the existing file.Also make sure that the folder `C:\Targetlocation` is existing, as this will not create the folder for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. i searched but i couldn't find anything that was what i wanted. 
is there an easy way to find whats the relative file path of a file in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

```
File.Copy(@"subfolder\\what i want to copy.txt", "C:\\Targetlocation\\TargetFilePath.txt");
```

> The sourceFileName and destFileName parameters can specify relative or
>   absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as
>   relative to the current working directory. This method does not
>   support wildcard characters in the parameters.

[File.Copy on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Make sure your target directory exists. You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory`

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Targetlocation");
```

With `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, you don't have to check if the directory exists. From documentation:

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they
>   already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. The path
>   parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path. If the
>   directory already exists, this method does nothing.

Comment: How do you handle the exception `Could not find a part of the path "C:\\Targetlocation"`. Please refer the link that you associated with your answer, you should give `destinationFilePath` not `destinationFolderPath`

Comment: You have to create c:\\targetlocation directory. You could use Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\targetlocation")

Comment: even then, you will get the same exception.you should give destinationFilePath not destinationFolderPath

Comment: OMG, still have issues, `Directory.Create` is not a method, you have to use `Directory.CreateDirectory()`

Comment: Now looks fine, but keep in mind this is not the way to give answers here

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove path from the file name.
    string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);

    try
    {
        // Will not overwrite if the destination file already exists.
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the relative path from your current working directory which can be checked via Environment.CurrentDirectoy.

For example if your current working directory is D:\App, your source file location is D:\App\Res\Source.txt and your target location is D:\App\Res\Test\target.txt then your code snippet will be -

```
File.Copy(Res\\Source.txt, Res\\Test\\target.txt);
```